# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController"

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

On Android api 27 emulator, there is an error message in Facebook Audience network 5.9.0:

```
I zygote  : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uJ>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:128)
   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:402)
   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
   at java.lang.String android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context) (WebSettings.java:1259)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.98.A01(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8C) (:19730)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.98.A04(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8C, boolean) (:19748)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.98.A06(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8k, com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8C, boolean) (:19789)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Xq.A76(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.91) (:59450)
   at void com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5p.A02() (:14381)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5p.getBidderToken(android.content.Context) (:14397)
   at void com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Xa.A06() (:59180)
   at void com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Kw.run() (:43315)
   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/Chrome/lib/x86, /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:128)
   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:402)
   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
   at java.lang.String android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context) (WebSettings.java:1259)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.98.A01(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8C) (:19730)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.98.A04(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8C, boolean) (:19748)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.98.A06(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8k, com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8C, boolean) (:19789)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Xq.A76(com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.91) (:59450)
   at void com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5p.A02() (:14381)
   at java.lang.String com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.5p.getBidderToken(android.content.Context) (:14397)
   at void com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Xa.A06() (:59180)
   at void com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Kw.run() (:43315)
   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
```

Does this occur on real devices?